# Drupal : content not displayed when logged-in

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Aloha,

I recently started a Drupal project (local) and I suddenly started to get an error that I don't really understand. It only happens when I'm logged-in.

The problem is that the content of the page doesn't display. I just get the tabs that allow me to modify the node or the page, and in the div "content", I just get this :

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/new/node/1/edit">Edit this node</a>
```

But when I'm not logged-in the content is correctly displayed. Have you ever seen this or any idea from what it can come?

I create my own theme and my template is pretty simple.

Thank you so much in advanced for any help <3

Plopen

Comment: I'm not sure if there is enough info here to accurately answer this. Perhaps provide screenshots & code segments to get best chance of resolution. Have you checked browser console for (javascript) errors; enabled maximum error reporting in PHP scripts for that page/view; checked for improper CSS rules, and checked the PHP logs, etc...? I would start with analyzing differences in markup/css by comparing everything in developer tools while logged in vs that of another browser not logged in side-by-side and see if it is front-end issue or back-end issue and go from there - process of elimination.

Comment: Also - I initially saw your question labeled as a Firefox issue only but I don't see that anymore - is it still only Firefox or does the same problem reproduce in Chrome/Chromium, Opera, Safari, and/or IE(10+)? If it works in other browser(s) than that is indicative that something is wrong client side while rendering pages with the supplied HTML/CSS or JS (if any).

Comment: Thanks for all your advices. First it only happened on ff, but I guess it was a cache problem on Chrome. And since I'm kind of a newbie, I didn't think about checking all the logs errors (PHP and JS). So thank you so much for this great advice that I'll keep in mind for a long time. I still haven't resolved my problem, but I'm gonna work on it today.

Comment: I tried to checked at the console and I don't get any error. When I look at the request of the page, I get everything except the content of the node... What can I provide you for helping you understanding the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem can (most likely) be in your theme or in your module (if you have one). Let's assume that you only have the theme.

First, try (temporary) switching to some default them and check is node editing working well. If it does (and probably it will) then try commenting out parts of your theme until you find out what's the problem. Start with template.php file if you have one. I.e. comment out whole file, then half of it, then a quarter (of course pay attention not to leave broken code!) until you localize the problem.

If that doesn't help try turning off some modules you installed. Again, if you have your module(s) start with them.

Comment: I tried to replace all my template.php and page.tpl.php by the default ones of bartik. I don't get any errors, but the problem still persists. So can I assume that the problem doesn't come from the template ?

I also tried to disable all the module that I installed but without success. But on the other hand  when I change to bartik theme, everything works fine, even with the module activate...

Comment: If it works fine when you change to Batrik theme then problem is obviously in your theme. When you replaced your theme files with batrik ones did you clear the cache?